# MacOS Catalina comes with Python 3.7.3, need to upgrade

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I recently upgraded to macOS Catalina and it seems to come with Python 3.7.3. All of my packages have come from the PIP installed with Python 3.7.3.

I have installed Python 3.7.7 (the newest version available on Homebrew), but it gives an error when linking. It tells me to run `brew link python3`, and when I do, it says

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/2to3
Target /usr/local/bin/2to3
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/2to3'
To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite python
To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run python
```

Previously, I accidentally uninstalled Python 3.7.3, which many people have recommended against because it is not a good idea to uninstall the macOS bundled Python and may cause issues with the operating system. I had lost all of the packages installed using PIP, and I had to restore my computer using my Time Machine backup to avoid issues with my operating system.

How can I make the newest version of Python (3.7.7) the default, and "transfer" my packages from PIP into the newest version of Python (if that is even required) and fix my Python installation?

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments? I would recommend doing so. _which many people have recommended against because it is not a good idea to uninstall the macOS bundled Python and may cause issues with the operating system._ Yes, it is generally not a good idea.

Comment: @VishnuS. you'll want to take a look at these for further reading:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html
https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html

Note, venv != virtualenv. They're two different things, though at the most basic levels, they achieve a similar concept. Virtualenv has slightly more functionality though. You'll want to avoid installing packages in your system python installation as much as you can, and use these instead. Makes things a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Python installation of 3.7.3 came with Xcode, so all I had to do was delete the app Xcode, and I ran a fresh installation of Python using Brew.

Answer (score 0):

yes you are right. New MacOs built in python3.7.3 in system and it comes from xcode, u dont't have to uninstall xcode

all you need to do is remove `/lib/commandlinetools/freamwork/python3.7.3`.

and install newest python with brew.

run `python3 --version` and `pip3 --version` they all newest from brew